# formatting POSIXct doesn't remove seconds

Tags: r, ggplot2, posixct

I am trying to create a `ggtitle` by formatting a `POSIXct` time stamp:

```
ggtitle(format(start_date, format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"))
```

However, the title keeps printing seconds too, as below. How can I get rid of them?
[image]

Comment: Please provide `dput(start_date)` or the equivalent.  I can't recreate this behavior using `format(Sys.time(), format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")`

Comment: I can't reproduce this with a simple `ggplot` either - `df <- data.frame(gp=1:5, y=2:6); ggplot() + geom_point(data = df, aes(x = gp, y = y)) + ggtitle(format(Sys.time(), format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"))`

Comment: are you sure `start_date` isn't just a character vector?

Comment: @rawr - good idea, but `format(as.character(Sys.time()), "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")` should error out. Until OP clarifies what they're working with, we're all stabbing in the dark.

Comment: @thelatemail not if the format is passed by name like in the example instead of by position like yours

Comment: @rawr - well spotted. `format(as.character(Sys.time()), format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")` does indeed just print the whole text. I reckon that's almost certainly the answer.